# Skype and VLC icons disappear from the menu bar

Tags: unity, icons, skype, vlc

I started using Ubuntu 3 days ago, but I don't know how to open Skype and VLC programs because their icons disappeared from the menu. I have already read answers to other people with similar problems, but I don't understand most of the technical language.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks for by part of that amazing community of Ubuntu... I'm free of windows, at least!

Answer (score 0):

Type `Ctrl-Alt-T` and a terminal will open. This is where you can type commands.

So you can type `skype` or `vlc` the nice trick is to type only a few letters and press the `tab key`, this will display all the commands that start with those letters.

There is a quick start for you ;)

PS: Type `nohup skype` and the terminal window will allow you to type more commands, but this is a temporary solution, you need to get a tutorial on adding menus

Comment: Guau!!!Thanks thanks thanks a lot dear!!!jeje....I'm really surprise how fast did you reply me. My problem whit it is solved!!!jeje..I hope must not do it any time that I want to open both programs...

Comment: Kein probleme mein freund

Comment: jajaja, I'm not German but it's OK..How could I vote you, please? I think you have already win it!! Mein freund..

Comment: You need more reputation, don't worry about it.